# Rotate, Scale, Translate in OpenLayers 4 and MapServer

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, mapserver, affine-transformation

Sometimes, I get spatial data (usually DGNs but I am not sure the format matters) that in the coordinate control sheet a 'Project Datum Factor' is noted. Say: `1.000073496`. If I add them as is in ArcMap, the features won't align with the rest of my data. So in order to align them correctly, I use the "Rotate, Scale, Translate" option in the Transformation tab from the layer properties dialog where I enter the quotient of 1 divided by the Project Datum Factor. In this example `0.9999265094094` as shown below:

[image]

After doing that, all the layers line up perfectly.

My question is- is there an equivalent workflow I can use in an OpenLayers/MapServer only environment? Not even sure at what stage or level I should try to apply the transformation. The layers are rendered in the OpenLayers map as WMS and/or WFS layers using MapServer. So could MapServer -somehow- apply the transformation and send the tranformed image or vector data to the OL map? Can OL -again somehow- apply this kind of transformation?

Comment: What format is the data in?

Comment: DGNs usually as I said

Comment: PostGIS has the ST_Scale function, but nothing similar in MapServer or ogr2ogr. It might be possible to define a custom coordinate system and to tell MapServer to convert from that. What is the original projection?

Comment: Kentucky Single Zone - EPSG:3089

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not in the EPSG:3089 coordinate system.

If you tell your software the *actual* coordinate system, then it is possible to convert the values into EPSG:3089 (or whatever you want to use).

EPSG:3089 uses a [Lambert Conformal Conic](https://proj.org/operations/projections/lcc.html) projection; in MapServer, it could be described with these parameters:

```
PROJECTION
    "proj=lcc"
    "lat_1=37.0833333333333333"
    "lat_2=38.6666666666666667"
    "lat_0=36.3333333333333333"
    "lon_0=-85.75"
    "x_0=1500000"
    "y_0=1000000"
    "ellps=GRS80"
    "towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
    "units=us-ft"
    "no_defs"
END
```

So in the layer definition, add this parameter (or maybe the reciprocal value) to correctly describe the custom coordinate system:

```
    "k_0=1.000073496"
```

(For the map and the other layers, you can use the `init=epsg:3089` short form.)

Comment: "Your data is not in the EPSG:3089 coordinate system." You mean the data I am trying to add? If so, yes, I guess you are right. But its pretty close I assume as it appears only slightly offset from all the other data. The current workflow is that we add these data using ogr2ogr as vector so I assume I will need to change/add the scale factor/k_0 at the time of load in OL. Many thanks. Gave me a few things to think about...